# how to create non removable account

Tags: android, user-accounts, accountmanager

I want to create a phone only account which will hold phone only contacts and use should not remove this account (except factory reset).

Is there any way,that can be specified either in account authenticator or sync adapter or via accountmanager such that this account will be non removable. any one of the following possibility is fine,
1). account will be present in the device but will not be available under configured account list in the account and sync settings
2). account will be available in the list but, remove option will be disbled (gone) for this account.

Thanks in advance,
AS

Comment: I don't think that wud be possible . Imagine an app/malware/virus once installed having these kinds of permission.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are good reasons why one would want such a thing. For instance, being able to keep the phone with 2 separate accounts: One for your data, one for phone management.
This way, if your phone gets stolen you can remotely control it via the phone management account while removing the data account.
Some Apps do allow you to remotely control your phone yet:
1) If you use only one account then once you change the password to protect your data you won´t be able to do thins like uninstalling apps remotely.
2) The thief being able to modify the accounts, there will be no way to avoid the management account to be removed.
3) The management account should be, preferably, hidden from the list of accounts so the thief doesn´t even suspect it´s there.

Going firmware makes sense, as it has been mentioned. I wonder if it´s that hard to implement. May post about it on XDA.

Cheers,
Jean

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but nothing you want in your list is possible, without firmware modifications.